# Assign a variable as the value for a jQuery ui progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

Im trying to create a progress bar with values being returned from a server. Im parsing this float and assigning it to a variable that im using as the value for my progress bar but it isn't being displayed. Im wondering if this has something do with my variable scope so that when the progress bar is being initialized my variable is undefined? I tried removing `var` to make it global but still no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onpejz4c/) example

**HTML**

```
<h3>Static Value</h3>
<div id="avg-1">
6.7
</div>
<div id="avg-wrap">

</div>

<h3>Dynamic Value</h3>
<div id="avg-2">
    6.7
</div>
<div id="avg-wrap2">

</div>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
//static value
$( "#avg-wrap" ).progressbar({
value: 6.7
});



var avg1 = document.querySelector('#avg-2').innerText;
parseFloat(avg1); 
avg1*10;

//dyamic value
$( "#avg-wrap2" ).progressbar({
value: avg1
});
```

Comment: `parseFloat` does not modify the value passed in parameter, you need to asign it `avg1 = parseFloat(avg1)`

Comment: also, `avg1*10` does nothing, you should use avg1`*=10`

Comment: I tried your code in the fidlle, and just by upgrading JQuery it worked [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s4m0gor/) (used jquery 1.11.0 yours was 1.10.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually global variable was not issue, issue was that you were not getting value from div correctly the correct way is

replace this

```
var avg1 = document.querySelector('#avg-2').innerText;
 parseFloat(avg1); 
avg1*10;
```

with this

```
var avg1 = $('#avg-2').html();
parseFloat(avg1); 
avg1=avg1*10;
```

Complete Sample

```
//static value
$( "#avg-wrap" ).progressbar({
    value: 6.7
});    

var avg1 = $('#avg-2').html();
parseFloat(avg1); 
avg1=avg1*10;

//dyamic value
$( "#avg-wrap2" ).progressbar({
    value: avg1
});
```

I have used jquery to access value
and then multiplied it by 10
and it worked cheers

[image]

Comment: care to explain? asside from replacing `.innerText` with `.html()` i don't see any difference

Comment: Thanks @litelite for pointing me to right direction, I'll update it

Comment: litelite its working in firefox browser, which browser you are testing IE?

Comment: Wow thanks. The reason i used `.innerText` was because incase there was any conflicts with the html coming from jQuery populating my div with the actual progress bar. `innerText` and `html()` both seem to work but my problem was solved when i changed `avg1*10` to `avg1 = avg1*10;` Do you know why that works? When you overwrite a variable globally it becomes accessible to other functions?

Comment: innerText was not working I tested using console.log(avg1); 
it was returning NaN, I don't know why, but one thing is clear Global variable is always accessible to other functions as soon as it has some value in it, hope you understand, thanks

Comment: no thank you! well i believe it was a string so when you parse it, it becomes a number (i think). but essentially i understand what was wrong thanks again.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan I am testing from IE 11

Comment: @litelite hmmm.... I was right, actually most of IE versions does not follow HTML CSS and JS Standards and thats why Microsoft has shifted to Edge Browser in Windows 10 and they will soon drop support for IEs, for simplest example you can search about setting FAV icon in html for IE is different then all other browsers

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan it is still a supported version, and not everybody have edge yet. (also yes IE is a compatibility nightmare, but unfortunatly it is still popular. you can't just tell you clients to update their browser specially since edge is Win10 only for now)